# Wordpress Category Page Pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I am just having a little different issue on category page. I don't want to show posts on category page. I am showing child categories of their parent category on category page so when user click on parent category then it will show how much that parent have child that children will show on category page with thumbnail. But now I am just having a issue that I want to show just 16 child categories and then I want to use `pagination` for next children. So anyone help please. 
Here is the code which I am using right now.

```
<?php
$thiscat =  get_query_var('cat'); // The id of the current category
$catobject = get_category($thiscat,false); // Get the Category object by the id of current category
$parentcat = $catobject->term_id; // the id of the parent category
$child = get_category_children( $thiscat, $before = '', $after = ',',  $visited = array() );
$num_cats  = wp_count_terms('category');
$num_parent_cats=count(get_categories('parent=0&hide_empty=0'));
$num_child_cats = $num_cats-$num_parent_cats;
if($child > $parentcat){
?>


    <div class="categories">

        <?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
        <?php if($cat->parent == $thiscat){ ?>
        <div class="main-subcat" style="display:inline-block">  
            <div class="thumb category-thumb" style="width:180px; display:inline-block;">
                <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />    
                <a class ="clip-link" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <h2 class="entry-title">
                    <a class ="clip-link" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
                </h2>
                <h4 class="entry-meta">
                    <?php echo $cat->category_description; ?>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </div>

<?php   
}
```

Comment: in case you want the SQL, this from the wp-includes/taxonomy.php should give you an idea

Comment: thanks deep but i don't understand will you explain it little more so i can understand

Comment: Please check the link here : http://forums.lesterchan.net/index.php?topic=4483.0